# Finally got my leader board up, but score is not showing up

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I finally got my leaderboard to show up. Now I just need to implement that my score will pop up.
My score is saved as an `NSString` in `NSUserDefaults` under the name `score`.

Here is some code:

**Game_CenterViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>
#import "GameCenterManager.h"

@class GameCenterManager;

@interface Game_CenterViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate, GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate, GKAchievementViewControllerDelegate, GameCenterManagerDelegate> {
    GameCenterManager *gameCenterManager;
    int64_t  currentScore;
    NSString *currentLeaderBoard;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) GameCenterManager *gameCenterManager;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int64_t currentScore;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* currentLeaderBoard;
@end
```

**Game_CenterViewController.m**

```
#import "Game_CenterViewController.h"
#import "AppSpecificValues.h"
#import "GameCenterManager.h"

@implementation Game_CenterViewController
@synthesize gameCenterManager;
@synthesize currentScore;
@synthesize currentLeaderBoard;

- (void)dealloc {
    [gameCenterManager release];
    [currentLeaderBoard release];
    [currentScoreLabel release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.currentLeaderBoard = thescore101;
    self.currentScore = score    
    if ([GameCenterManager isGameCenterAvailable]) {
        self.gameCenterManager = [[[GameCenterManager alloc] init] autorelease];
        [self.gameCenterManager setDelegate:self];
        [self.gameCenterManager authenticateLocalUser];
    } else {
        // The current device does not support Game Center.
    }
}

- (void)leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
    [viewController release];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    self.gameCenterManager = nil;
    self.currentLeaderBoard = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

The current score is where I'm trying to put the `NSString` in.

Comment: if you guys want me to include my game manager files let me know I am trying to keep this sort as possible.

Comment: Why are you using int64_t instead of NSInteger?

Comment: I was just using this tutorial and I have pretty much no idea where to go from here. I thought it was pretty useful considering i can get on my game center now. Do you want my game manager?

Answer (score 0):

*EDITED: I think it would be better to use int for the currentScore.*

Is this what you are looking for?

```
- (void)submitMyScore:(int64_t)score
{

    GKScore *myScoreValue = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"yourCat"] autorelease];
    myScoreValue.value = (int)score;

    [myScoreValue reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){
        if(error != nil){
            NSLog(@"Score Submission Failed");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Score Submitted: %d",(int)score);
        }

    }];
}
```

So you should add a `IBAction`

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed
{
    [self submitMyScore:currentScore];
}
```

With this and connecting the SEND MY SCORE button to this IBAction, you will have your score submitted.

I hope this to be useful for you.

Comment: Is there a way to send it automatically. I always thought that you had to have a  view table to use iboutlet. Also is the your cat a string?

Comment: @JhonDoe yourCat is the name of the leaderboard registered in itunes connect and it is a string. To send it automatically just call `[self submitMyScore:currentScore];`

Comment: use the self submitmyscore after void submit my score right? Also, i believe my biggest problem is i have a string with nsuserdefaults with the object key score and i have to somehow replace current score with it